Unauthorized access Transformer.js even when i am authenticated using huggingface-cli
I was trying to experiment with transformers.js with microsoft phi-3
import { pipeline } from "@xenova/transformers";

const generator = await pipeline(
  "text-generation",
  "microsoft/Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct"
);

const response = await generator(
  "Instruction: Explain quantum computing in simple terms\nResponse:",
  {
    max_new_tokens: 150,
    temperature: 0.3,
  }
);

console.log("response", response);


Although I'm authenticated using huggingface-cli with the access token, I get this error.
file:///Users/vignesh/projects/yt-mate/node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/models.js:5526
            throw Error(`Unsupported model type: ${config.model_type}`)
                  ^

Error: Unsupported model type: phi3
    at AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained (file:///Users/vignesh/projects/yt-mate/node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/models.js:5526:19)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async loadItems (file:///Users/vignesh/projects/yt-mate/node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/pipelines.js:3279:5)
    at async pipeline (file:///Users/vignesh/projects/yt-mate/node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/pipelines.js:3219:21)
    at async file:///Users/vignesh/projects/yt-mate/src/utils/summarize.js:3:19

Node.js v20.18.1

Am I missing anything?
